# which datatype should I use for date in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The [offical docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) says "(Date datatype is) stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch".

And [this blog](https://mixmax.com/blog/30x-faster-elasticsearch-queries) says "we achieved a 30x performance improvement in Elasticsearch queries by switching from millisecond timestamps to seconds".

Should I use "long datatype" to store date(and store in seconds, not milliseconds) directly?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't quite mention any other different date store method so it's a bit hard to say. (not that I know anything about the subject, but it's an interesting topic and I would love to see the results)